# How to use add_rewrite_rule to pass through variables?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

How can I have something like site.com/foo/entries/doedit?id=57 redirect to site.com/foo?section=entries&action=doedit&id=57

If the process is different, could I please get help rewriting site.com/foo/doedit?id=17 to site.com/foo?action=doedit

Thank you!

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule` is generally used to mask one URL in WordPress with something else. `.htaccess` is usually used to 301/302 users from one URL to another. (Both can be used for either, I'm just generalizing.). What do you want to do, passively route users, or actively redirect them?

Comment: Does `foo` represent a slug for a post or page, represent a multisite sub-directory, or represent a [front](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/) (*Anything up to the start of the first tag in your $permalink_structure.*) from the permalink structure? This matters for how `foo` would be treated in the `add_rewrite_rule` substitution string.

Comment: Yes foo would be a front page.